# Rails model specs passing, Sidekiq spec failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, sidekiq

I'm building a Rails (4.1.0) app that runs a poll. each poll has `n` Matchups with `n` Seats. Here are my models:

```
class Matchup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :seats, dependent: :destroy

  def winning_seat
    seats.sort { |a,b| a.number_of_votes <=> b.number_of_votes }.last
  end
end

class Seat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :matchup

  validates :matchup, presence: true
  validates :number_of_votes, presence: true

  def declare_as_winner
    self.is_winner = true
    self.save
  end

end
```

My specs for Matchup and Seat pass without issue. At the end of a poll, I need to display the winner. I am using a Sidekiq worker to handle the end of the poll. It does many things, but here's the code in question:

```
class EndOfPollWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

def perform(poll_id)
  poll = Poll.where(:id poll_id)
  poll.matchups.each do |matchup|
    # grab the winning seat
    winning_seat = matchup.winning_seat
    # declare it as a winner
    winning_seat.declare_as_winner
  end
end
end
```

The spec for this worker doesn't pass:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'EndOfPollWorker' do
  before do
    #this simple creates a matchup for each poll question and seat for every entry in the matchup
    @poll = Poll.build_poll  
  end

  context 'when the poll ends' do
    before do
      @winners = @poll.matchups.map { |matchup| matchup.seats.first }
      @losers = @poll.matchups.map { |matchup| matchup.seats.last }
      @winners.each do |seat|
        seat.number_of_votes = 1
      end

      @poll.save!

      @job = EndOfPollWorker.new
    end

    it 'it updates the winner of each matchup' do
      @job.perform(@poll.id)
      @winners.each do |seat|
        expect(seat.is_winner?).to be(true)
      end
    end

    it 'it does not update the loser of each matchup' do
      @job.perform(@poll.id)
      @losers.each do |seat|
        expect(seat.is_winner?).to be(false)
      end
    end

  end

  end
end
end
```

When I run this spec, I get:

```
EndOfPollWorker when poll ends it updates the winner of each matchup
     Failure/Error: expect(seat.is_winner?).to be(true)

       expected true
            got false
```

My specs for the Seat and Matchup models pass just fine. I cut a lot of the test code out, so excuse any mismatched tags, assume that's not the problem!

Also, when the workers actually run in development mode, the seats.is_winner attribute isn't actually updated.

Thanks

Comment: Sidekiq woker only accept string params, are you sure you can pass a instance to that woker? And are you start any sidekiq woker?

Comment: you're right! I copied over incorrectly. I'll updated the code. I was trying to simplify but I introduced an error. I think the @job.perform starts the worker, right?

Comment: `@job.perform` just send a work to sidekiq queue, then you need to start a sidekiq worker in command like [bundle exec sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/), then that work would be performed. And worker need a few second to finish it, so you may `sleep n` to wait for it.

Comment: thanks @dddd1919. I have it running, but the tests still fail. Also, when I run the application itself, the is_winner attribute isn't actually updated. I think the test is correct, but don't know how to fix the issue.

Comment: Think you can do `mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'` in your routes.rb to init a sidekiq visual panel and go visit `/sidekiq` to see if work is deliverd and run correct

Comment: I think I mis-worded my question. I have no doubt the tests are running. The 'winning_seat.declare_as_winner' isn't actually working from the working. Running it in the console and in the seat spec works. It just isn't working either in the actual worker that runs or in the worker spec. make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Sidekiq has nothing to do with your problem.  You're directly calling perform so the issue is with rspec and activerecord.  For instance, pull the code out of the perform method and put it directly in the spec, it should still fail.

I suspect the instances are stale and need to be #reload'd from the database to pick up the changes done in #perform.